# Bool issues. And, or, and or, or not

Tags: python, boolean

I'm trying to run a code using bool but I'm having issues with getting the code to work. Basically I have to use the code to decide if it's safe to drive after meeting certain criteria. The battery has to be charger(True), I have to have a car(True), I cannot be drunk(False), I must have enough gas to get where I'm going, and if it's night time I must have working head lights. So far I've manged to get all the way through to the gas part but I cant seem to figure out the and, or, and not, or not statements when it comes to driving at night or day with working and non-working head lights.

```
battery_charged=True
got_car=True
drunk=False
gas=2 # (gallons) # gas currently in the tank of the car
distance=100 # miles from home
mpg=35 # miles per gallon expected to be used driving home
nighttime=False
headlights_out=False

can_drive=(battery_charged and got_car and not drunk and \
               (gas*mpg>=distance) and (nighttime and not headlights_out))

if can_drive:
    print("Drive home")

else:
    print("Don't drive home.")
```

Comment: Hint: if it's daytime, do you care about the headlights?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the final clause:

```
and (nighttime and not headlights_out)
```

This says that you can drive only at night with your headlights on.  What you need to say is that *if* it is nighttime, the headlights must be on.  The logical equivalent easiest to code is "It must be daytime, or my headlights must be on":

```
and (not nighttime or not headlights_out):
```

That should get you on the road ...